# Volatile in struct causing warning in macro

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, volatile

I use the following type:

```
/* double_buffer.h */

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t * active_buffer_p;       //< Address of active buffer
    uint8_t current_writing_index;   //< Current writing index in active buffer
    uint8_t buffer_1[BUFFER_SIZE];   //< First buffer
    uint8_t buffer_2[BUFFER_SIZE];   //< Second buffer
} double_buffer_t;


#define DoubleBuffer_init(buffers) do {                 \
        (buffers).active_buffer_p = (buffers).buffer_1; \
        (buffers).current_writing_index = 0;            \
        } while(0)
```

In my code, I declare an array of double buffer, using the **volatile** keywoard (because the buffers can be updated/read asynchronously in interrupts and in functions):

```
static volatile double_buffer_t m_double_buffers[NB_DOUBLE_BUFFERS];
```

I then initialize those buffers individually:

```
DoubleBuffer_init(m_double_buffers[id]);
```

When I compile the software (gcc), I got the following warning:

```
 error: assignment discards 'volatile' qualifier from pointer target type [-Werror=discarded-qualifiers]
   28 |         (buffers).active_buffer_p = (buffers).buffer_1; \
```

The reason why I have this warning is quite unclear to me, and I am not sure how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated (I can update the question if something is not clear).

Comment: Note that `volatile` does not mean "atomic".  It's impossible to tell without specifics, but what you've posted opens to door to some nasty race conditions.

Comment: https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p5:  "When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by receipt of a signal, the values of objects that are neither lock-free atomic objects nor of type volatile sig_atomic_t are unspecified, as is the state of the floating-point environment. The value of any object modified by the handler that is neither a lock-free atomic object nor of type volatile sig_atomic_t becomes indeterminate when the handler exits, as does the state of the floating-point environment if it is modified by the handler and not restored to its original state."

Comment: Critical sections are implemented in order to avoid race conditions

Comment: The problem is that members of `volatile` structure also get `volatile` qualified. The the pointer type of `double_buffer_t::active_buffer_p` is missing `volatile` qualifier.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Who said it made anything atomic? That's not why you declare variables shared with an ISR as `volatile`. Every single time someone brings this up, we always get these irrelevant rants about "volatile and thread safety" in comments. Where are the threads? Who claimed `volatile` is there to prevent data races? Nobody! So kindly delete those off-topic comments and check out this: [Using volatile in embedded C development](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/409570/6102)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this warning because you have a volatile object, and you create a non-volatile pointer to it.

This is bad as the compiler could access the volatile object without knowing that it is volatile. E.g. it could transform two reads into a single, it could change the order etc.

One way to fix it is to define `active_buffer_p` to `uint8_t volatile * active_buffer_p`.

Comment: Yes but members of the struct are supposed to become volatile as well (since I declare the whole variable as volatile). So I don't understand why I should explicitly tell that active_buffer_p  is volatile.

Comment: @The_Average_Engineer: You're confusing a volatile pointer with a pointer to volatile data. `active_buffer_p` will be a `uint8_t* volatile` when the whole struct is `volatile`. That means the pointer itself can change without notice.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a `struct` variable as `volatile`, each member object gets `volatile` qualified, as if you had written the struct like this:

```c
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t* volatile active_buffer_p; 
    volatile uint8_t current_writing_index;
    volatile uint8_t buffer_1[10];
    volatile uint8_t buffer_2[10];
} double_buffer_t;
```

That is, in case of a pointer member, the pointer itself turns `volatile`. `type* volatile` = the pointer's address may change at any moment. And not what it is supposed to point at. `volatile type*` = the pointed-at data might change at any moment.

And therefore when you assign, `buffer_1` "array decays" into `volatile uint8_t*` and then you try to assign that to a pointer qualified as `uint8_t* volatile`. The pointer types aren't compatible since they have different qualifiers.

The solution is to declare the pointer member `volatile uint8_t* active_buffer_p;`. Then if the struct variable is declared `volatile`, this becomes `volatile uint8_t* volatile` (the pointer and what it points at may change at any moment). And we can always assign a "non qualified" pointer to one with more qualifiers, but not the other way around.

`const` works exactly the same way.

---

As a side note, that init macro is just ugly and fills no purpose but obfuscation. Consider dropping it in favour of readable code:

```c
static volatile double_buffer_t m_double_buffers[NB_DOUBLE_BUFFERS] =
{
  [0] = { .active_buffer_p = m_double_buffers[0].buffer_1, 
          .current_writing_index = 0 },
  [1] = { .active_buffer_p = m_double_buffers[1].buffer_1, 
          .current_writing_index = 0 },
  [2] = { .active_buffer_p = m_double_buffers[2].buffer_1, 
          .current_writing_index = 0 },
};
```

Or 100% equivalent:

```c
static volatile double_buffer_t m_double_buffers[NB_DOUBLE_BUFFERS] =
{
  [0] = { .active_buffer_p = m_double_buffers[0].buffer_1, },
  [1] = { .active_buffer_p = m_double_buffers[1].buffer_1, },
  [2] = { .active_buffer_p = m_double_buffers[2].buffer_1, },
};
```